# Can we approximate the below equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

A^2+B^2 to (A+B)^2
In which are the situation do we take such equility .
In some books I see these are taken ,
Below third equation in the image approximated ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08yJI.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08yJI.jpg)

Comment: When you expand $(A+B)^2$, what do you get?

Comment: Sure, in a field of characteristic 2...

Comment: `In some books I see these are taken.` Would you care to quote an example of such.

Comment: I doubt anyone takes them to be equal. In some situations, it's enough that they be within a constant multiple of each other; in other situations, it may be all you need is $a^2+b^2\le(a+b)^2$ (provided $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative).

Comment: Got answer now , made mistake while taking

Comment: In terms of complexity (big-O notation) they are the equivalent, maybe you saw that in books about computer science or algorithms.